# MDT UEFI Low Resolution

Tags: drivers, uefi, resolution, winpe, mdt

Computer: OptiPlex 3080 w/ Intel UHD 630 graphics

When I try to boot to MDT, the resolution seems to be stuck at 800x600.  This causes issues as the layout of the wizard gets moved around.

How can I set it to 1024x768 or better yet, 1920x1080 (or auto select).

I've tried:

- Injecting video drivers into WinPE ISO (Used Intel UHD driver pack from dell.com)
- Setting `Xresolution`, `Yresolution`, etc in customsettings.ini and boostrap.ini
- Changing the resolution in the unattend.xml file at `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Deployment Toolkit\Templates\Unattend_PE_x64.xml`
- Disabling secure boot

None of these have had any effect.  I tried both 1024x768 and 1x1 in all spots.

How can I get MDT WinPE to boot at the correct resolution?

## EDIT:

Related to [ventoy/Ventoy#502](https://github.com/ventoy/Ventoy/issues/502)

Comment: A [BIOS update](https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us/product-support/product/optiplex-3080-desktop/drivers) is available, dating from 27 Aug 2021. Try it (carefully) to see if it helps.

Comment: @harrymc The BIOS is already up to date.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem deploying Windows 10 21H2 m the WinPE version 10.0.19041.1.
Were you able to solve your problem, if so, how?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1147466)

Comment: I was not able to.  Further, the problem seemed to be related to loading ISOs via Ventoy.  Directly flashed images did not exhibit this issue.

Comment: It is unfortunate that I am inconveniencing you (Rohit Gupta) with my approach.
Actually, I just wanted to leave a comment to ask my question if @cclloyd found a solution to his problem. 
Unfortunately, due to my novice status, I am not able to upvote or comment on anything. I apologize for this.